# How to resample with different offset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different time series data which have a different time scale. One has hourly data where the value for `12:00:00` contains the average of the data from `11:00:00-12:00:00`. Times are in german.

The other data set has values for every minute and when I do a resample in pandas with `resample('h').mean()` I get a value for `12:00:00` which contains the average from `12:00:00-13:00:00`.

Sample data hourly data, will remain unchanged, here `07:00:00` contains the average of the data from `06:00:00-07:00:00`:

```
date                 value           
2020-08-03 05:00:00  276
2020-08-03 06:00:00  852
2020-08-03 07:00:00  642                    
2020-08-03 08:00:00  564
2020-08-03 09:00:00  756
2020-08-03 10:00:00  234
```

Sample data minute values:

```
date                 value           
2020-08-03 05:00:00  276
2020-08-03 05:01:00  852
2020-08-03 05:02:00  642                    
2020-08-03 05:03:00  564
2020-08-03 05:04:00  756
2020-08-03 05:05:00  234
2020-08-03 05:06:00  342                    
2020-08-03 05:07:00  123
2020-08-03 05:08:00  656
2020-08-03 05:09:00  645
```

When I now resample this with `df2.resample('h').mean()` I get a value for `05:00:00` which contains the average from `05:00:00-05:09:00` and therefore I can't compare this with the data in df1, there the value from `05:00:00` is from the previous hour.

How can I resample the second time series so that when I have the value for `05:00:00` it is from `04:00:00-04:09:00`?

Comment: Please provide a sample input data and expected output along with what your code is doing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `label='right'` argument to the `resample` method -

```py
df2.resample('h', label='right').mean()
```

**Output**

```
                     value
date                      
2020-08-03 06:00:00    509
```